# Different images on same thing

Tags: support

Is that default behavior, to show the global badges per sub-site specific images?

for example, look this:

[image]

Comment: You've noticed that the style is set by the site you are on not the site that the icon (or other GUI element) relates to; I'm not sure what the problem/question is.